# Customer Name Not Showing In Header section Magento 2

Tags: customer, magento-2.2.5, toplinks

In my module, I did forcefully logged in to the customer without a password. And After logged in customers redirect to the Homepage only. And everything works as expected, except customer name not showing in Header user links.

Note:- I am working Magento 2.2.5 Enterprise version of Magento.

```
public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $customer = null;
    $placeHolderCustomer = null;
    if (isset($data['winid']) && isset($data['email'])) {
        try {
            $placeHolderEmail = $data['winid'].self::DEFAULT_PLACEHOLDER_EMAIL;
            $placeHolderCustomer = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->get($placeHolderEmail);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $noSuchEntityException) {
            $urlKey = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
            $this->_redirect($urlKey);
            return false;
        }

        try {
            $customer = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->get($data['email']);
            $this->updateCustomerAddressInfo($placeHolderCustomer, $customer, $data['winid']);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $noSuchEntityException) {
            if (!is_null($placeHolderCustomer)) {
                try {
                    if (isset($data['firstname']) && isset($data['lastname'])) {
                        $customer = $this->saveCustomerAccountData(
                            $placeHolderCustomer,
                            $data['email'],
                            $data['firstname'],
                            $data['lastname']
                        );
                    } else {
                        $customer = $this->saveCustomerAccountData($placeHolderCustomer, $data['email']);
                    }
                    $this->saveCustomerAddressData($placeHolderCustomer, $customer);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {

                    $urlKey = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
                    $this->_redirect($urlKey);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        $customerId = (!is_null($customer)) ? $customer->getId(): null;
        if (!is_null($customerId)) {
            $searchCriteria = $this->getCustomerAddressSearchCriteria($data['winid'], $customerId);
            $customerAddressesResult = $this->customerAddressRepositoryInterface->getList($searchCriteria);
            if ($customerAddressesResult->getTotalCount() > 0) {
                // Updating existing customer name, received from post data
                if (isset($data['firstname']) && isset($data['lastname']) && $placeHolderCustomer == null) {
                    $customer->setFirstname($data['firstname']);
                    $customer->setLastname($data['lastname']);
                    $this->customerRepositoryInterface->save($customer);
                }

                $items = $customerAddressesResult->getItems();
                $shippingAddress = (isset($items[count($items) - 1])) ? $items[count($items) - 1]: $items[0];
                $customerZipCode = $shippingAddress->getPostcode();

                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $customerData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerId);

                $this->_session->loginById($customerId);
                $this->_session->setWinId($data['winid']);
                $this->_session->setZipCode($customerZipCode);
                $this->_session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customerData);
                try{
                 if ($this->cookieManager->getCookie('mage-cache-sessid')) {
                        $metadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory->createCookieMetadata();
                        $metadata->setPath('/');
                        $this->cookieManager->deleteCookie('mage-cache-sessid', $metadata);
                    }
                    $customerFullMessage = 'Welcome, '.$data['firstname'].' '.$data['lastname']. ' ,You are successfully Logged In to the System';
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__($customerFullMessage));
                } catch (\Exception $exception) {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                        __('An error occurred while processing your login. Please try again later.')
                    );
                }




                // if(isset($data['catId'])){
                    // $categoryObj = $this->categoryRepository->get($data['catId']);
                    // $urlKey =   $this->categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($categoryObj);
                // } else if(isset($data['urlkey'])){
                    // $categories = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()
                                // ->addAttributeToFilter('url_key',$data['urlkey'])
                                // ->addAttributeToSelect(['entity_id']);
                    // $categoryId = $categories->getFirstItem()->getEntityId();
                    // $categoryObj = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
                    // $urlKey =   $this->categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($categoryObj);
                // } else if(isset($data['part_number'])){
                    // $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/singlesignon.log');
                    // $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
                    // $logger->addWriter($writer);
                    // $logger->info('Your text message');
                    // $logger->info(print_r($data['part_number'], true));

                    // if($this->_product->getIdBySku($data['part_number'])) {
                        // // if(isSalable){

                        // // } else{
                        // // }
                        // $_product = $this->productRepository->get($data['part_number']);
                        // $urlKey = $_product->getProductUrl();
                        // $logger->info(print_r($urlKey, true));

                    // } else{
                        // $urlKey = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
                    // }

                // } else {
                    // $urlKey = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
                // }
                // if(empty($categoryObj)){
                    // $this->_redirect($urlKey);
                // }else{
                    // //$urlKey =   $this->categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($categoryObj);
                    // $this->_redirect($urlKey);
                // }

                if(isset($data['part_number'])){
                    if($this->_product->getIdBySku($data['part_number'])) {
                        $_product = $this->productRepository->get($data['part_number']);
                        if(in_array($placeHolderCustomer->getWebsiteId() , $_product->getWebsiteIds())){
                            if($_product->isSalable() == 1){
                                if($_product->isAvailable() == 1){
                                    $urlKey = $_product->getProductUrl();
                                } else{
                                    $urlKey = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
                                }
                            } else {
                                $urlKey = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
                            }
                        } else {
                            $urlKey = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
                        }
                    } else{
                        $urlKey = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
                    }
                } else{
                    $urlKey = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
                }                       
                $this->_redirect($urlKey);



            } else {
                $urlKey = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
                $this->_redirect($urlKey);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            $urlKey = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
            $this->_redirect($urlKey);
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        $urlKey = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
        $this->_redirect($urlKey);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to find out the actual problem?
[image]

Comment: please share code screenshot please

Comment: Please check my edited comment

Comment: so what other data you will get? email , customer id?

Comment: Are you able to resolve this issue? @NilavaChakraborty